# Vue 2: configure router to navigate to other product using relative path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am new to vue but I need to fix some issue.

I have app with some products and its verions. I am able to view details of some version when accessing the path: `/products/details/productId/versionId`
Let's say I am accessing product A and its version 1 and path to it is:
`/products/details/product_A_Id/version_1_Id`

In the description of this product version there is a link to different product and different version set as:
`<a href="product_B_Id/version_1_Id">Product_B/Version_1</a>`
So when I am accessing this link I am redirected to: `/products/details/product_A_Id/product_B_Id/version_1_Id` and then redirected to 404 as  there is no such path.

After changing link to `<a href="../product_B_Id/version_1_Id">Product_B/Version_1</a>` I am redirected to correct product and correct version. But the issue is that there are a lot of links that are pasted in without `../` and using some db script will not be an easy solution.
Is there any easy way that will fix above issue? Any router method that will do what it takes to nevigate me to correct product version?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `<router-link to="/product_B_Id/version_1_Id">Product_B/Version_1</router-link>`

Comment: I would like to use some method or better navigationGuard that will help with redirecting me to correct page

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it by adding children path in vue router and redirecting it to page `productId/versionId`:

```
{
    path: 'products/details/:productid',
    name: 'productsdetails',
    component: ProductDetails,
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: ':productid/:versionid',
        redirect: {
          name: 'releaseDetails',
        },
      }
    ]
  },
```